# Returning value from method and "The Value Assigned Is Never Used"

Tags: java, arrays, return

I'm following Princeton's introductory computer science course (I'm not a student, just teaching myself). I working on this [assignment](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ysLYdL7pMSNk0nGsG7YFzj1IhwAhGu28edgt1Uma4s0/edit).

Main is calling two methods: amplify and reverse, both of which return an array. Amplify multiplies all values in the array by a constant alpha. Reverse returns an array that lists the original array values in reverse order, ex. {1,2,3} -> {3,2,1}.

Amplify works fine, but nothing happens when I call reverse and I get a bug that states: [The Value Assigned Is Never Used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhHAz.png)

```
public class audiocollage {
    // Returns a new array that rescales a[] by a factor of alpha.
    public static double[] amplify(double[] a, double alpha) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = a[i] * alpha;
        }
        return a;
    }

    // Returns a new array that is the reverse of a[].
    public static double[] reverse(double[] a) {
        double[] b = new double[a.length];
        for (int i = a.length - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++) {
            b[j] = a[i];
        }
        return b;
    }

    // Creates an audio collage and plays it on standard audio.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] samples = StdAudio.read("cow.wav");
        double alpha = 2.0;

        samples = amplify(samples, alpha);
        samples = reverse(samples);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. The compiler is just pointing out that after you assign the return value of `reverse` to `samples` the value in `samples` is not used. What do you mean "nothing happens when I call reverse"? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: you do nothing with `samples` (after assigning the result from reverse), so the Java compiler warns you, that this assignment is unnecessary (you could just do `reverse(samples);`).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have two questions:

1. Why doesn't anything happen when I call `reverse(samples)`?

The code you're showing does nothing with the result of `reverse(samples)` other than store it in the variable `samples` (overwriting its previous value). You will need to do something with `samples` after that to observe the new array (like printing `samples`, which should now appear to be reversed).

Which leads into the next question:

2. Why do I get a warning about "the value assigned to `samples` is never used"?

This is a warning saying that the code you wrote doesn't do anything.
`Dead store to local variable` is the first line of the warning, which describes what's happening: the value stored to `samples` is "dead" -- it is never used again, and so we may as well have skipped that line altogether. That causes your compiler (or extension) to give us a warning because it's almost certain that the code you wrote is *not* doing what you intended, so in many cases that warning can be helpful for spotting mistakes.

This warning can be resolved by using `samples` somehow, such as by printing it, calling another function with it, etc.

The previous line

```
 samples = amplify(samples, alpha);
```

doesn't generate that warning because it's output is used in the following call to `reverse()`:

```
samples = reverse(samples);
//                  ^ usage of `samples` variable!
```

This is made even clearer by using different variables for all your arrays:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // No warning; samplesRaw used later
        double[] samplesRaw = StdAudio.read("cow.wav");
        double alpha = 2.0;

        // No warning; samplesAmplified used later
        samplesAmplified = amplify(samplesRaw, alpha);

        // WARNING! samplesReversed is never used!
        samplesReversed = reverse(samplesAmplified);
    }
```